# Laravel 5 Blade двойное использование директивы @include. Дублируется первый

Tags: laravel, include

Наткнулся на такую проблему:

```
@include('views.some1')
@include('views.some2')
```

Содержимое some1

```
@extends('layouts.wd')

@section('wd-content')
<div class="some-1">
     some 1
</div>
@endsection
```

Содержимое some2

```
@extends('layouts.wd')

@section('wd-content')
<div class="some-2">
     some 2
</div>
@endsection
```

Результат инклудится:

```
 <div class="some-1">...</div>
 <div class="some-1">...</div>
```

Если инклуды поменять местами

```
@include('views.some2')
@include('views.some1')
```

То будет

```
 <div class="some-2">...</div>
 <div class="some-2">...</div>
```

Comment: Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос нужно еще больше подробностей. Покажите дерево папок ваших шаблонов, и где конкретно вы инклудите эти шаблоны.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f7zbc9

Comment: Так ничего и непонятно. Где находится секция wd-content, где происходит непосредственно инклуд файлов? Если вы хотие в wd вывести some 1 - some 2, тогда вам нужно убрать из views.some1 и views.some2 @extends('layouts.wd') и @section('wd-content'), прописав в wd инклуды в нужном месте. Но пока это вилами по воде, так как задача не раскрыта до конца.

Comment: Код wd.blade 
http://prntscr.com/f8r9t6
Это шаблон так сказать окна на сайте. И вот представьте что на странице мне нужно вызвать 2-3 или четыре окна. Для того что бы их не дергать ajax-ом то я их включаю на страницу через @include('views.some2')
@include('views.some1')

Answer (score 0):

Нужно что бы название секции было уникальным, передайте туда уникальное значение:

```
@extends('layouts.wd')

@section('wd-content' . $num)
   <div class="some-{{ $num }}">
         some {{ $num }}
    </div>
@endsection

@include('views.some2', [ 'num' => 1])
@include('views.some1', [ 'num' => 2])
```